# hiding & showing DIVS via Radio button group selection using JQuery

Tags: jquery

here's what i want to achieve:

1. Have a grouped radio button with different values
2. Selected radio will reveal specified div $('#group1').Show() & $('#group2').Hide()

My question is: How do I do get the value of the selected radiobutton from the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the :checked selector, e.g.:

```
$('input[name=selector]:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name=GroupName]:checked").val();
```